# wifi not working in ubuntu 13.04 on lenovo g430

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom, lenovo

I have lenovo g430 system in which my wireless card is **bcm4312** . i just installed ubuntu 13.04 on my lenovo system along with windows 7 . All things are working properly except my wireless not detecting any wifi connection .

From what i do till now is:

1. when i write "iwconfig" on terminal it shows me "no wireless found"
2. i tried to install my wireless driver using software update in system setting in the additional driver option . its shows my wireless but cant update it

please help me regarding this issue .
thanks in advance :)